# Uncaught ReferenceError: OCA is not defined in nextcloud

Tags: javascript, owncloud, nextcloud

While I'm configuring object storage in next cloud it will show error like **Uncaught ReferenceError: OCA is not defined**
[image]

Added object storage parameter in config.php file. Following is my configuration file.

```
    'objectstore' => array(
        'class' => 'OC\\Files\\ObjectStore\\S3',
        'arguments' => array(
            'bucket' => 'abcbucket',
             'autocreate' => true,
             'key'    => '09KDDKXI8783343FSDX34',
             'secret' => 'SDF987SD9F879dsf897DSF98798798DSF98dsf98798DSF',
             'hostname' => 's3.wasabisys.com',
             'port' => 443,
             'use_ssl' => true,
             'region' => 'us-east-1',
             // required for some non amazon s3 implementations
             'use_path_style'=>true
        ),
      ),
```

How can I fix this problem in nextcloud?

Comment: In my case, I removed the instanceid line and it worked again.